# Where can I write the after query logic in RetrieveAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Where can I write the after query logic in RetrieveAPIView?

In my models.py I have a Message class:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    message
    """
    message_num = models.CharField(default=getMessageNum, max_length=16)  

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    is_read = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    create_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_messages")
    receive_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="received_messages")

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the views.py:

```
# the message list
class UserMessageListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserMessageSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        messages = user.received_messages.all()

        return messages

# the message detail 
class UserMessageRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserMessageSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        messages = user.received_messages.all()

        return messages
```

You see, in the `UserMessageRetrieveAPIView` I can retrieve the message instance.
How can I do the logic to set the message's `is_read` ? Where I can set it?

---

**EDIT**

I mean, if its possible, I want to get the retrieved message, then updated it, but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: mmm.....why not make a db update call just before `return messages` with all `message_num`?

Comment: How can I get the id?

Comment: so this is more of a design discussion than code issue! :) what is the purpose of  `user.received_messages`?

Comment: the `user.received_messages ` means the user's received messages. (user1 send to user2, the user2 receive the message)

Comment: okay, something like *whatsapp*, are you not storing the message mapping any where? *which* `message` was sent to *whom* and *when*?

Comment: you have wrong focus here buddy, your design should revolve around messages and not users. Users should be a foreign key entity of signed-up users! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class UserMessageRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserMessageSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        messages = user.received_messages.all()

        return messages

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.is_read = true
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```